# I would like to make a call using one button and use one fixed number

Tags: java, android, phone-call

I would like to make a call using one button. The phone number should be inside. But my code is inoperative. Who can support?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button button;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}

public void onClickStart(View view) {
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
   
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) v -> {

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        String phNum = "tel:" + "89261234567";
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phNum));
        startActivity( callIntent) ;
    });

}
```

}

## manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.GateApp">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're never assigning the click listener to the button, since onClickStart is never invoked. This is how you should do it

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) v -> {

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        String phNum = "tel:" + "89261234567";
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phNum));
        startActivity( callIntent) ;
    });
}
```

This way you're assigning the click listener to the button. In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button) you can find how to use it.

[Here it is the link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Phone) at the call intent documentation

Answer (score 0):

Just use this two lines of code inside onClickListener:

```
 ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) v -> {
            String phNum = "tel:" + "89261234567";
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phNum, null)));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add to manifest file this string
<data android:scheme="tel" />

Answer (score 0):

// This works well!

((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) v -> {

```
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        String phNum = "tel:" + "87777777777";
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phNum));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    });
```